# NestJS - question regarding service-mocking

Tags: dependency-injection, mocking, nestjs

I'm currently rewriting our plain node API-server in NestJS and I've encountered the following issue: I have a `CacheService` which acts as a wrapper around redis and which is injected in various other services.

Now, if the client-request contains a custom-header (key: `x-mock-redis`, value: `someRedisMockKey`) and if the server runs in debug mode, instead of calling redis, a mocked json-value should be returned (the value is read from a file with the name `someRedisMockKey`).

I could set the scope of my `CacheService` to "Request" and inject the client-request, allowing me to check if the mocking-header exists and return the mocked value there if running in debug-mode.
But I find this counterintuitive as I'd have logic violating the single responsibility principle and which should not run in production-mode. Also I'd prefer my `CacheService` to have default scope instead of "Request".

Any recommendations how to do this more elegantly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In advance, sorry if I misunderstood the question or constraints, will try to paraphrase them and point out how it should look like, I suppose.

- production always uses Redis
- you can set up the app instance on different port so that it is fully separated from 'staging' (or other) app instance

If you can fulfill the second condition, you can make use of custom modules and apply different client-wrapper (strategy) for your service:

Custom provider for `Cache module`

```
import * as redis from 'redis'
import { INTERNAL_CACHE_CLIENT, INTERNAL_CACHE_MODULE } from './cache.constants'
import { CacheModuleAsyncOptions, InternalCacheOptions } from './cache.module'
import CacheClientRedis from './client/cache-client-redis'
// ...

export const createAsyncClientOptions = (options: CacheModuleAsyncOptions) => ({
  provide: INTERNAL_CACHE_MODULE,
  useFactory: options.useFactory,
  inject: options.inject,
})

export const createClient = () => ({
  provide: INTERNAL_CACHE_CLIENT,
  useFactory: (options: InternalCacheOptions) => {
    const { production, debug, noCache, ...redisConfig } = options
    // pardon for the ifs ; )
    if (noCache) {
      return new CacheClientInMemory()
    }
    if (production) {
      return new CacheClientRedis(redis.createClient(redisConfig))
    }

    if (debug) {
      return new MockedCache()
    }    

    return new CacheClientMemory()
  },
  inject: [INTERNAL_CACHE_MODULE],
})
```

as noticed, you can have any wrapper around CacheClient, which, in your case, would serve data from file. For simplicity, the example of interface being implemented by any cache client could be:

```
export interface CacheClient {
  set: (key: string, payload: string) => Promise<boolean>
  get: (key: string) => Promise<string | null>
  del: (key: string) => Promise<boolean>
}
```

Now on, as we have let the module decide which strategy should be used, service just needs:

```
constructor(
    @Inject(INTERNAL_CACHE_CLIENT) private readonly cacheClient: CacheClient) {
  }
```

Feel free to point out if it still breaks principles or you really need to decide it during runtime.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for your interesting input. The problem is I really need to decide what to use during runtime (i.e. as I tried to describe when the client sends the specific header). Any idea?

Comment: Would move the responsibility to the CacheClient instead but it is very similar to the service itself, however ClientImplementation would behave as a strategy in this case :shrug: